# Gradle failed to resolve: com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, android-instrumentation, spoon

I'm trying to use the Spoon plugin for my Instrumentation Tests, but I am unable to proceed with a Gradle error unable to resolve dependency `Failed to resolve: com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT`.

I used this guide: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/gradle-spoon-plugin/blob/master/README.md

My actual top build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath 'com.jaredsburrows:gradle-spoon-plugin:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

repositories {
    // For Spoon snapshot, until 2.0.0 is released
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}
```

My module build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.jaredsburrows.spoon'

// other necessary stuff here

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Is my setup incorrect? or is there something I missed?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is already resolved. The maven repository should be placed inside my build.gradle's `allprojects` section.